# How to count duplicates based on other column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Here is a sample table that mimics my scenario:

```
COL_1   COL_2       
1       a               
2       a               
9       b               
8       b               
11      b
```

I have two columns where Column 1 have different numerical values and Column 2 represents different classes (a, b, c, etc.). In column 3 I would like to have them counted per class and matched with 0/1 numbers based on what was the biggest/lowest value in Column 1. So if in my example class "a" have only two values (in our example 1 and 2) they should be counted from 0 to 1 (where 0 stands for lowest number and 1 for biggest from Column 1). If class b is being represented by 3 entries I would like to have them matched by 0/1/2 numbers based on what is the biggest/lowest number from Column 1 in "b" class.

After my query I woul like to have  something like this:

```
COL_1   COL_2   COL_3   
1       a       0       
2       a       1       
9       b       1       
8       b       0       
11      b       2
```

So, in other words I want a query that looks how many duplicates we have in column 2 and gives them values from lowest to biggest (where 0 is lowest) based on what they are  represented in column 1.

Thanks to anyone who helps me with this.

*I am using MS SQL, if that would make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: I've got through my O'Really SQL cookbook and some online tutorials but couldn't find the correct answers and my own solutions were not working. I'm new to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    col_1,
    col_2,
    row_number() over(
        partition by col_2 order by col_1
    ) - 1 as col3
from yourtablename
```

Comment: +1 . . . Even though you should subtract - 1 to get values starting at 0.

Comment: consider adding some comments to your solution and formatting the code, it will make it more understable for the OP and future visitors